# how to use progressive jpegs magento

Tags: php, magento

I have to problem with Magento.
I am testing speed of your site on http://www.webpagetest.org/ 
and result is "Use Progressive JPEGs: 0/100"

How to increase the point of using progressive JPEGs?
I've read the guide here but it's not successfully. My magento version is 1.9.0.1
[link](http://pushentertainment.com/test/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Centos,**

1. Go to terminal
2. yum install jpegoptim
3. Go to the folder containing images, which you want to optimize and run following command.
4. find . -iregex ".*.jpe?g" -exec jpegoptim --max=80 --strip-all --all-progressive {} \;

**For Ubuntu,**

1. Go to terminal
2. sudo apt-get install jpegoptim
3. Go to the folder containing images, which you want to optimize and run following command.
4. find . -iregex ".*.jpe?g" -exec jpegoptim --max=80 --strip-all --all-progressive {} \;

for more details please refer below links,

https://www.webmaster.net/tutorials/install-jpegoptim-in-ubuntu-or-centos-compress-your-images-losslessly-to-optimize-google-pagespeed-score.html